# iOS video recording duration update UI

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, avfoundation, gpuimage

I'm using GPUImageVideoCamera and GPUImageMovieWriter to record a video. Everything is working good except I want to show the user a progress bar with the duration as the movie is being recorded. The GPUImageMovieWriter has a property called Duration, but I'm not sure how to make it update the UI in real time (as the video is being recorded).

I just need someone to point me in the right direction on how I can achieve this, I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a NSTimer to fire once every second or two and update the progress bar.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that before but couldn't get it to work. Just realized it had to be added to a run loop.